# Buggy code in A tour for C++ about initializing a vector with switch in lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda

I am reading *A Tour of C++* second edition. At the end of Chapter 6.3.3 it gives an example to initialize a vector by a lambda with switch statement in it. The code doesn't seem to compile.

The code in the book looks like this:

```
vector<int> v = [&] {
    switch (m) {
    case zero:
        return vector<int> (n);
    case seq:
        return vector<int> {p,q};
    case cpy:
        return arg;
    }
};
...
```

It seems he defined a lambda here, and directly assign it to `vector<int> v`, instead of call it and assign the return value. I tried to chang it to this and it workds:

```
std::vector<int> v = ([&] () -> std::vector<int> {
    switch (f) {
    case Fruit::apple:
        return std::vector<int> (1);
    case Fruit::banana:
         return std::vector<int> (2);
    case Fruit::cherry:
         return std::vector<int> (3);
    case Fruit::dragonfruit:
         return std::vector<int> (4);
    }
   return std::vector<int> (10);
 })();   
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

My question is, is the book wrong or did I miss something? Is there a standard way to initialize an object by directly assign a lambda to it?

Comment: The code in the book obviously is incomplete; it lacks a `;`.  What else it lacks?  I am no mind reader.

Comment: Sorry I omitted the `;` It actually has it.

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/tour2_errata.html